# adding another input field to laravel's basic auth system

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i was trying to add another input field that will get validated and is required. i am following a turtorial by freecodecamp which explains it but somehow it still wont work for me

here is my coding:

i've tried going over everything again 2 times.
i've tried some stuff on my own but it didn't work so i reversed it

here is the code.

user table model:

```
<?php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

here is the field i added in my register.bade file:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" username="username" value="{{ old('username') }}"  autocomplete="username" autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

registerController:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {   
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

and the user.php:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password'
    ];
```

after i did all this to add a username i migrated the table as followed:

```
php artasin migrate:fresh
```

so i though it would work like it did in the video but now when i fill in the form i get a validation saying i have to fill in the form(while i did) and nothing ends up in my database

Comment: Can you post your AuthController?

Comment: actually, your input for username doesn't have a "name" attribute.

Comment: oke this fixed it thanks. i accidently changed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your error. You didn't quite define your input field name right in the `register.bade` file. You currently have it like this:

```
<input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" username="username" value="{{ old('username') }}"  autocomplete="username" autofocus>
```

In this input, you have **username="username"** which ins't right definition of input field name, and so Laravel doesn't register this field even when you fill it, but it looks for name="username", which you don't have on your form, and you get the validation error.

Change it to this:

```
name="username"
```